# method with return type class object

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, singleton

Write a method with

return type MyClass object and with multiple parameter

i tried

```
-(MyClass *Obj)mymethod:(NSString*)name withAge:(int)age
{
//do stuff
Obj.name=name;
Obj.age=age;
return Obj;
}
```

In some other class where i want to call this above function ,how i call it?

Comment: do u mean something similar to singleton class ?

Comment: yes check modified question, how i call it in my other class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the method like:

```
 -(MYClass *)myMEthod:(NSString *) name withAge:(int)age
   {
         MYClass *myObj=[[MYClass alloc]init];
         myObj.name=name;
         myObj.age=age;

        return myObj;
    }
```

If you want it to be singleton, then use static object and dispatch_once

TO make this a singleton:

```
 +(MYClass *)myMEthod:(NSString *) name withAge:(int)age
   {
        static MYClass *_myObj=nil;

        static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _myObj = [[MYClass alloc]init];
    });
          _myObj.name=name;
          _myObj.age=age;
        return _myObj;

    }
```

And in other class, you can simply import this class, and call it by

```
  [MYClass myMethod:@"" withAge:12];
```

Comment: i need to get return type MYClass to be get in some other variable like we simply do with other return type method 

NSString *getResponse=[self mymethod:@"good"];



-(NSString*)mymethod:(NSString*)setname

 {

returen setname;
}

Comment: yes you can do like  myClassObj=[MYClass myMEthod:@"" withAge:12];

Comment: means MYClass * myClassObj=[MYClass myMEthod:@"" withAge:12];
or
CurrentClass *myClassObj=[MYClass myMEthod:@"" withAge:12];
where CurrentClass is the class from where i call it?

Comment: no you should not use current class object, you should always use MYClass obj to store the reference of MYClass obj.